# Как при клике на + и - менять ссылку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вообще не могу додуматься как сделать такое? у нас есть костыльный магазин и раньше продавали товары поштучно, сейчас же перешли уже на выбор количества. Пока делается нормальный магазин, надо решить эту задачу, а я никак не могу как сделать чтобы при клике на + и - менялся ссылка добавления в корзину?
Есть ссылка в карточке товара

```
<a class="buy_button" href="/addtocart.php?id=387&q=1" rel="nofollow">Добавить в корзину</a>
```

Сделал в карточке товара инпут

```
<div class="kolvo">
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<span class="plus"></span>
</div>
```

Как мне увеличивать и уменьшать количество в ссылке q= ?, это еще при том что на странице могут быть несколько товаров
Код кнопок

```
$('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count;
        if($input.hasClass('isdbl')){
            count = parseFloat($input.val()) - parseFloat($input.attr('step'));
            count = count < parseFloat($input.attr('step')) ? parseFloat($input.attr('step')) : count;
        }
        else{
            count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        }
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        if($input.hasClass('isdbl')){
            $input.val(parseFloat($input.val()) + parseFloat($input.attr('step')));
        }
        else{
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
        }
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Как вариант - обработать клик по ссылке и просто взять значение из `input`. После этого уже можно будет сделать переход по сформированному УРЛ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**:

Как вариант:

```js
var addToCartLink = document.querySelector('.buy_button').getAttribute('href');
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.kolvo input');
var plusButton = document.querySelector('.kolvo .plus');
var minusButton = document.querySelector('.kolvo .minus');

// Функция для обновления ссылки при изменении значения input
function updateLink() {
  var inputValue = inputElement.value;
  var newLink = addToCartLink.replace(/q=\d+/, 'q=' + inputValue);
  document.querySelector('.buy_button').setAttribute('href', newLink);
}

// plus
plusButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inputElement.stepUp();
  updateLink();
});

// minus
minusButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inputElement.stepDown();
  updateLink();
});

// Обработчик события при изменении значения input
inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  updateLink();
});
```

```html
<a class="buy_button" href="/addtocart.php?id=387&q=1" rel="nofollow">Добавить в корзину</a>

<div class="kolvo">
<span class="minus">-</span>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
<span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает, но не подскажите как делать чтобы при нажатиях кнопки тоже значение менялось? так работает если я вручную меняю через сам input, добавил код кнопок

Comment: @reddyk обновил код

Comment: Смотрите если внутри карточки товара она работает идеально, но если на странице категории, то только 1 карточка товара работает(

Comment: @reddyk на странице категории нужно пройтись по всем элементам, querySelector выдаёт только первый элемент из всех

Comment: queryselectorall  выдает ошибки

Answer (score 0):

> а я никак не могу как сделать чтобы при клике на + и - менялся ссылка добавления в корзину?

Как вариант - поместить значимые элементы в один контейнер и далее отработать по следующему сценарию.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (!o.classList.contains('buy_button')) return
  e.preventDefault()
  const op = o.closest('.cart')
  const v = op.querySelector('input').value
  const url = o.href + '&q=' + v
  console.log(url)
  // делаем переход
  //top.location = url
})
```

```html
<div class='cart'>
  <a class="buy_button" href="/addtocart.php?id=387" rel="nofollow">Добавить в корзину</a>
  <div class="kolvo">
    <span class="minus"></span>
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
    <span class="plus"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```